# google apps script output email body line by line

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet script that captures the body of a specific email with a table in it. Up to now, this has been working fine, but I have now hit the 50000 character limit for a single cell issue. I was using:

=transpose(split("C1", CHAR(10),TRUE))

in order to split the contents line by line, so now need to script this instead, so that the email body is delivered to the sheet line by line, row by row.

What is my best approach for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself eventually, with thanks to the elite responders on here (Serge/Mogsdad/Sandy et al), whose answers to previous questions provided all the clues. Using Serge's getMessage code in the first place. Better ways than using appendRow, I know, but some would not work with the poorly formed html content of the message (e.g. putting the lines into an array caused an error about range width). My script calls just one email, the latest one with the selected label.

Below is the function that covers it:

```
function getMessageWithLabel() {
 var destArray = new Array();
  var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('<GMailLabel>').getThreads(0,1);

  for(var n in threads){
        var msg = threads[n].getMessages();
        var destArrayRow = new Array();
        destArrayRow.push('thread has '+threads[n].getMessageCount()+' messages');
          for(var m in msg){
            destArrayRow.push(msg[m].getBody());
           }
  destArray.push(destArrayRow);           
        }

  //open spreadsheet and set sheet for appending data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('<Google Spreadsheet ID>');
  var sh5 = ss.getSheets()[4];

  //get number of lines in content
  var lines = destArrayRow[0].split('\n');
  var length = lines.length;

  //appendRow for each line in content  
  for (var i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
   sh5.appendRow([lines[i]]);
  }

}
```